# Is it possible to use an external field in the calculation for a pivot table column?

Tags: mdx, pivot-table, olap, cube

Let us say we have a pivot table, that lists different departments of a school district. (each department being a unique row).

The number of hours of work put in by each department is the 2nd column of the pivot table.

I want to create a 3rd column that lists "dollar amount" spent by each department.

The issue being 'hourly rate' is not part of the cube that is used to generate the pivot table.. The excel spreadsheet has a manually written table that has 2 columns, (Dept, hourly rate).

I am wondering if it is possible to use the external table column 'hourly rate' using my olap mdx calculation?

Comment: did my answer help answer the question? (although I think there is no specific answer as what you describe is not possible so a workaround may be the only solution)

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer, Yea the issue is, if I convert to formula then I loose some of the 'powers' of the cube... and I cannot add the hourly rate to the cube either (business procedures)... hence kinda stuck.

Comment: You say the second column is Num of Hours - is this a measure? If you are using the latest excel then, I think, you could add a custom measure with a complicated Case statement in it. I will try to model and add to my answer.

Comment: it is not pretty but it works: let me add some screenshots

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're asking if you can add some sort of Lookup functionality inside a custom measure to find values that are in the spreadsheet but not in the cube. I don't believe this is possible.

What is possible is the following.

Create a pivot table looking at your cube - this is mine against the AdvWrks cube:

[image]

Now, with the pivot table selected, hit this button:

[image]

You can now add a standard `vlookup` formula and drag down the right hand side:

[image]

Notice how the slicer of the pivot table has remained  - so all formulas are still linked through to your OLAP cube.

The above is possibly some sort of route you might like to explore as a workaround ....or just add some more information into the cube!!

---

**EDIT**

This is not a very elegant solution but it is a way you can add your rate into the pivot:

In here select "MDX Calculated Measures..."

[image]

Then for my advWrks prototype I added this `mdx`:

```
case 
when [Product].[Product Categories].CURRENTMEMBER IS [Product].[Product Categories].[Category].[Accessories] then 0.5 
when [Product].[Product Categories].CURRENTMEMBER IS [Product].[Product Categories].[Category].[Bikes] then 2.5 
when [Product].[Product Categories].CURRENTMEMBER IS [Product].[Product Categories].[Category].[Clothing] then 5
else 1
end
*[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
```

The above measure is called `fooBar` and can now be used in the pivot along with any other measure:

[image]

If there are 600 categories then my case statement will be pretty ugly - but it seems to be functioning as expected.

Answer (score 0):

the previous answer gives your best options with pivot tables. 
XLCubed (full disclosure, who i work for) is an add-in which handles this sort of limitation in olap connected Excel, & your scenario is detailed below. Basically a grid (pivot table equivalent) retrieves the SSAS data, and you can then add a user calculated column containing any standard Excel formula, in your case a vlookup:

http://blog.xlcubed.com/2016/06/calculated-fields-are-not-available-in-an-olap-based-pivot-table/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.